# MeteorJS ReactiveVar with database data

Tags: meteor

Clearly, I am doing something wrong with ReactiveVar because I cannot get it to work as I expect it should.

I am trying to set the value of an ReactiveVar by calling a Meteor.call method which returns the list of usernames. But it does not update when the usernames get changed in another part of the app.

I tried both:

```
Template.qastatistics.created = function () {
  this.trackUsernames = new ReactiveVar(false);
  var instance = Template.instance();
  Meteor.call('trackUsernames', function (err, data) {
    instance.trackUsernames.set(data);
  });
};
```

and:

```
Template.qastatistics.helpers({
  users: function () {
  var usernames,
  instance = Template.instance();
  if (instance.trackUsernames.get() === false) {
    Meteor.call('trackUsernames', function (err, data) {
      instance.trackUsernames.set(data);
    });
  }
  usernames = instance.trackUsernames.get();
  ...
```

But neither updates the list of usernames when these change in the database.

Is this even possible with ReactiveVars or have I completely misunderstood them?

**EDIT:** The usernames I mention are not from Meteor.users collection, but rather a distinct call from another collection that has usernames in it.

Comment: Yes. I get the data correctly once. But it does not update when the data changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to suggestions from @kyll, I managed to get what I wanted by publishing the data I need:

server:

```
cope.publish.usernamesID = Random.id();
Meteor.publish("itemsusernames", function () {
    self = this;

    var initializing = true;
    var handle = Items.find().observeChanges({
        added: function (id) {
            !initializing && self.changed(
                "itemsusernames",
                cope.publish.usernamesID, 
                Items.distinct("p4User"));
        },
        changed: function (id) {
            !initializing && self.changed(
                "itemsusernames",
                cope.publish.usernamesID, 
                Items.distinct("p4User"));
        },
        removed: function (id) {
            !initializing && self.changed(
                "itemsusernames",
                cope.publish.usernamesID, 
                Items.distinct("p4User"));
        }
    });
    initializing = false;

    self.added("itemsusernames", cope.publish.usernamesID, Items.distinct("p4User"));
    self.ready();

    self.onStop(function () {
        handle.stop();
    });
});
```

client:

```
users: function () {
    var usernames = [],
        oUsernames = ItemsUsernames.find().fetch();

    if (!oUsernames[0]) return [];

    usernames = $.map(oUsernames[0], function (value, index) {
        if (!isNaN(index)) {
            return [value];
        }
    });
    ...
```

And ofcourse: `ItemsUsernames = new Mongo.Collection("itemsusernames");`

Answer (score 2):

Fist of all I would use the `onCreated` function instead of defining `created`. That's a little more extendable and it's the new API. `created` is just kept around for backwards compatibility.

About your problem. You are right, you seem to have misunderstood what `ReactiveVar`s do. They are a reactive data source. That means that when you call `myReactiveVar.get` in some `Tracker.autorun` (aka. reactive computation), the computation will rerun whenever `myReactiveVar.set` is called.

You got the first part right. Spacebars helpers always run inside their own computation. What you got wrong is thinking that a method call is a reactive action. That means, that you could call `trackUsernames` and set the `trackUsernames` `ReativeVar` again and the value in your template would update itself. But a method is only run once. It doesn't do anything fancy with reactivity.

A method call only transfers data once. When you publish a set of documents (like all users) on the other hand, they will be updated dynamically. Whenever a change happens inside that set of published documents, it will be synced to the client. **So in general, it's a better idea to use publications and subscriptions to sync data reactively**. If you'd want to use a method for the same thing you'd need to do some kind of polling (so your back in the stone-age again).

The easiest way to implement what you are trying to do is to use `Meteor.users.find().fetch()`. As it says in [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) `fetch` registers dependencies for all the documents you are fetching if it's being called from within a reactive computation.

First you'll need to properly set up your publications, so that users can see other users usernames. I'll leave that to you. Then you need to reimplement your helper

```
Template.qastatistics.helpers({
  users: function () {
    var usernames = _.pluck(Meteor.users.find().fetch(), 'username');
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I should have clarified that usernames are not from the users collection. I have a large table of items which have usernames in them, in different params, like "p4user" for example. I am extracting distinct usernames from that collection to populate a dropdown in a filter... I wanted to move this calculation to the server, since the collection is becoming very large...

Comment: @PredragStojadinović You can, methods and publication only differ from one another in purpose. A method is a one-shot call to retrieve data, where a publication is rather here to reactively notify the client for updates through DDP.

Comment: @kyll Sorry, I did not understand your comment :( You say "You can", but I don't understand what is it that you are referring to...

Comment: I meant, "you can move this calculation to the server". Do whatever it is you have to do on the server, then if the result of these actions are reactive, [publish them](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) to the client.

Comment: @kyll, this is going good, so far. The only thing I cannot find is how to remove an item from published self when it is removed from the underlying collection. It requires an ID which is randomly created in my case and cannot be anything else :(

Comment: @kyll, after playing with it, I got it to work as expected. Thanks!